# Saving files without a trailing newline

Tags: gedit, text-processing, ubuntu-mate, text-editor, pluma

Recently I discovered that, after years of thinking various software was adding a newline to the end of my files, it was actually Pluma (or Gedit -
 same difference) silently adding them all along. Currently I'm working on a website that will have lots of PHP includes, parsing data saved on disk and the likes, so it would make my life a lot easier to do away with the extra line added to the end of each file. As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to stop this behaviour.

I'd like to either get this sorted or find a text editor similar to Gedit without this issue. I don't really want to resort to using Notepad++ via Wine, but that may be an option. Terminal text editors are also a possibility but I'd rather use one with a GUI for anything more than minor edits to files.

Comment: In Linux and other Unix-like operating systems non-empty text files end with a new-line character by convention. Do you have a specific reason to break that convention? PHP interpreters should be able to deal just fine with them.

Comment: @DavidFoerster They cause a line break when I'm using PHP includes, reducing markup readability in the output, which I feel is an important aspect during the development process for debugging and the likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conf in gedit that can correct your problem :
You can modify it by typing

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor ensure-trailing-newline false
```

---

If you don't like command line tools 
You can modify it using `dconf-editor` (`sudo apt install dconf-editor` if needed)

Then in dconf-editor go to

```
/org/gnome/gedit/preferences/editor
```

And change `ensure-trailing-newline` to false

Comment: Is there an equivalent setting for Pluma or should I just install Gedit? I found various settings for Pluma in dconf but none relating to trailing newlines.

Comment: I have no idea for Pluma, sorry

Comment: Gedit doesn't look how I remember. Anyway, this seems to work so I'll use it for my newline-sensitive files.

Answer (score 1):

The following editors do not add a trailing newline character, if there is none,

- leafpad
- emacs

You can install both via the repositories

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install leafpad emacs24
```

(I checked in 16.04 LTS, and it was the package emacs24 for my emacs.)

Edit:

- `leafpad` is a light-weight GUI editor, that comes with Lubuntu.
- `emacs` is a classic editor originally from Unix, and it can be run both with a GUI and in a terminal window. It is very powerful, but has a learning curve.

Comment: Leafpad isn't what I'm looking for. Emacs was a good suggestion, but I don't think I'll be using it.